# Android - Changing position of a marker dynamically with google maps api

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, marker

I am writing an application to track a device that emits its current coordinates (longitude and latitude) to a server.  I am trying to constantly update a marker on my map using google maps api.  However, I have been very unsuccessful in this.

I am parsing the data from a server so I have the coordinates I need to update the marker to.  However, if I do marker.remove(), or marker.setPosition(latilongi), the application only draws the last coordinate that has been parsed from the server.

If anyone has any insight on how to achieve this affect of being able to run the android app and see the marker dynamically change, it would be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is happening when you use `marker.setPosition(latilongi)`??

Comment: It will just set the marker to the last position that is parsed from the server and it will not display the marker in the positions prior to the final position

Comment: so you want the previous markers to be there with the newly added marker..right???

Comment: Not really, I want the marker to act like the current location marker, in that it is constantly moving when your location is changing.

Comment: ooo totally confused...isnt that what you are actually getting now???

Comment: Yeah, this is the problem I am dealing with!
For some reason it is not working like that..
I am calling my functions that parse the server and call the update method, from my onCreate method. Perhaps this is not right?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this to move the marker with animation use this:

```
  /**
   * @param marker the operation marker
   * @param finalPosition the destination latlng
   * @param latLngInterpolator interpolator of animation
   */
static void animateMarkerToICS(Marker marker, LatLng finalPosition, final LatLngInterpolator     latLngInterpolator)
```

this is the code:
https://gist.github.com/broady/6314689

and the video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WKfZsCKSXVQ

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use either `animateCamera()` or `updateCamera()`

You can find some details below, but basically if you know the new center of the map you will be doing something like this:

```
public void centerMapAt(LatLng latLng) {
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
}
```

or

```
public void centerMapAt(LatLng latlng, LatLngBounds bounds) {
    int padding = 100; 
    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, padding);
        getMap().animateCamera(cameraUpdate);       
}
```

There are many options.

http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/CameraUpdateFactory.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#animateCamera(com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate)

Comment: OKay, thanks. I will give this a try and see!
Is it correct for me to call this method from my onCreate() method?

Comment: I think you would want to call this every time you get a new location from your server.  What I do is poll my server every 10 secs while the map is active, so every 10 seconds I get a new location and then update the my markers and recenter the map via a cameraAnimate(newLocation);